# How to build list of variables in make runs and use it for post-processing

Tags: list, shell, recursion, makefile

I need to call submakes recursively with different variable settings. During this, I need to build a list of the variable settings. After all submakes are complete, I need to check the results of all the submakes using the list built up.

```
tests:
    echo "Testcase 1 $(testname)..."; \
    $(MAKE) -e TESTCASE=1 guimode=no run > test.tc1.log; \ # must save variable TESTCASE_LIST = {1} or similar
    $(MAKE) -e TESTCASE=2 guimode=no run > test.tc2.log; \ # must append to variable TESTCASE_LIST = {1 2}
    $(MAKE) -e TESTCASE=2 guimode=no run > test.tc3.log; \ # must append to variable TESTCASE_LIST = {1 2 3}
    echo "Completed Tests at time $(realtime) ..."; \
    $(MAKE) check_test_results;  # must run through results of tests 1,2,3 and get data

check_test_results:
    for testcase in $(TESTCASE_LIST); do something; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub-make is a child process, so it cannot transfer environment variables to its parent. I suggest simply to examine exit codes and process them inside `tests` recipe, kind of:

```
.ONESHELL:
tests:
    $(MAKE) TEST=1 ... && TESTCASE_LIST+=(1)
    $(MAKE) TEST=2 ... && TESTCASE_LIST+=(2)
    ...
    # check results
    echo "Successful tests: $${TESTCASE_LIST[@]}"
```

Comment: This cannot work because `TESTCASE_LIST+=(1)` is a syntax error in the shell and these are shell statements, not make statements.

Comment: @MadScientist Well, it works in modern bash, and also, probably, in zsh and some others. Not really portable, I agree, however it was rather for illustrative purposes.

Comment: If you want to use bash-specific syntax you must add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile.  But I don't see any point in requiring magical shell features when you can just use `TESTCASE_LIST="$TESTCASE_LIST 1"` etc.